# cannot specify root sdk directory with syslibroot when linking

Tags: macos, ld

I have a few static libraries I want to link with `ld`. My libraries are in the directories `/Users/rlt/p4/lib/` and `/Users/rlt/p4/usr2/lib`. I want to pass in the relative paths of these directories w.r.t `/Users/rlt/p4` and use the `-syslibroot` to point to this directory. The documentation for `ld` says that this option `will prepend a pre-fix to all search paths`.  However, the following command gives me directory not found errors for both paths I specify:

```
ld -syslibroot /Users/rlt/p4 -L/lib -L/usr2/lib -lA -lB -lC
```

This gives me could not find `/lib` and `/usr2/lib`. I tried using `-Lusr2/lib` and `-Llib` with same results. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-syslibroot` does not prepend its argument string to arbitrary paths. It will only add it to the paths which are consistent with the sdk directory structure.