# gcc linker can't find library (openNI)

Tags: matlab, compilation, ld, mex, openni

Can anybody give me some hints for solving this?

I'm trying to compile ["Kinect Matlab"](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30242-kinect-matlab) (on Mac OS 10.7), in the compile script is the following line:

```
mex('-v','-L/usr/lib/','-lOpenNI',[...],Filename);
```

This is the full command run by mex: **(1)**

```
gcc-4.2 -O -Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch x86_64 -Wl,-syslibroot,/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -bundle -Wl,-exported_symbols_list,/Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/extern/lib/maci64/mexFunction.map -o  "mxNiChangeDepthViewPoint.mexmaci64"  mxNiChangeDepthViewPoint.o  -L/usr/lib/ -lOpenNI -L/Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/bin/maci64 -lmx -lmex -lmat -lstdc++
```

Then I'm getting the following error:

```
ld: library not found for -lOpenNI
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

    mex: link of ' "mxNiChangeDepthViewPoint.mexmaci64"' failed.
```

There is most definitely a file at `/usr/lib/libOpenNI.dylib`.

What kinds of things cause `ld` to throw this error?

#### What I tried:

- I have tried creating a symlink called `libOpenNI.so`, like jmlopez suggested, no effect.
- Could it be that `libOpenNI` is a 32bit library, and `ld` is not seeing it for that reason? Or would the error then be different?
- Regarding the point above, it says that the build is "universal x86/x64"

#### Env vars:

I've tried to add the library to the environment variables using the following command, from the matlab terminal. No effect.

```
setenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH', [getenv('DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH') ':/usr/lib/']);
```

#### In bash:

Just calling gcc as suggested here https://serverfault.com/questions/54736/how-to-check-if-a-library-is-installed gives no problems.

```
$ gcc -lOpenNi
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
```

However, if I run g++ first, then gcc as in **(1)**, same error as before. (library not found). How come gcc can find the library, but when matlab adds the stuff in **(1)** it messes things up?

So, related to what is said above, I started removing all arguments from **(1)** until I got a different error. I removed the `-Wl,-syslibroot`, meaning that -syslibroot would no longer be passed to `ld`, this seems to have fixed it. So `-syslibroot` is messing up the library search directory! Now to find a way to remove this argument from the `mex()` call.

Comment: I had a similar problem before when I was using gcc. I don't quite remember if the extension was dylib, but what I ended up doing was creating a symbolic link to it. So, since you have libOpenNI.dylib, try creating a link to it with the name libOpenNI.so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## BOOM! IT WORKS!

Okay, here it is:

The `-Wl,-syslibroot` option in the gcc call **(1)** is sending a `-syslibroot` option to the linker, and somehow that gets prepended to the library search path (even though it shouldn't according to [cannot specify root sdk directory with syslibroot when linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216434/cannot-specify-root-sdk-directory-with-syslibroot-when-linking))

So, removing this `-syslibroot` can solve our problem, this can be done in `mexopts.sh`. Copying matlab's version from the default location:

```
cp /Applications/MATLAB_R2011a.app/bin/mexopts.sh ~/.matlab/R2011a/
```

And then changing this line (201):

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-twolevel_namespace -undefined error -arch $ARCHS -Wl,-syslibroot,$SDKROOT -mmacosx-version-min=$MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET"
```

Removing the `-Wl,-syslibroot,$SDKROOT` argument.

Additionally, I could remove the `-L/usr/lib` argument from the call to mex, making it simply:

```
 mex('-v','-lOpenNI',['-I' OpenNiPathInclude],Filename);
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you trying adding `OpenNi` to your `LIBRARY_PATH` ?

`export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/YOUR-PATH/OpenNi`

Comment: But how do I enter this in a terminal so that Matlab knows?

Comment: @Noio: You have to put it as an environmental variable where `gcc` or compile `make` is running. You can simply put it before the `make` or compile command as `LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/YOUR-PATH/OpenNi make`. Or, as I have shown before `export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/YOUR-PATH/OpenNi; make`

Comment: `gcc` is running from matlab when you call `mex()`. So the environment would be the matlab terminal. I am not running `make` from a normal terminal.

Comment: Additionally, shouldnt the `-L` switch take care of this?: *"[...] LD_LIBRARY_PATH will also be searched at link (ld) stage after directories specified with -L (also if no -L flag is given)."*

Answer (score 1):

First option: if libOpenNi isn't of the same architecture as the binary you're compiling, the whole compiler suite will likely ignore it. If you did manage to get it to link anyway, it would probably crash. Find a native 64 bit library and link against that.

Second option: I'm not 100% sure on this, but whenever I've tried doing linking on some esoteric linux projects, I start with a .a object archive in the path specified by `-L`. If it links, then I'll add `-fPIC -shared` on x86_64 to get it to compile against the shared library. I'm not sure if this will work on OSX: I've never done development on that platform yet.

Comment: If it's the wrong architecture, would the linker throw that kind of warning ("not found")? The library is "universal x86/x64".